# Copy data from second datagridview to first datagridview while the first datagridview has already a data in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

How can i copy data from one datagridview to another? I want to copy the data from second datagridview to first datagridview while the first datagridview has already data.

For example this is my first datagridview:

```
ID  |  Name   | City
----+---------+---------
1   |  Alex   | New York
2   |  Mark   | New York
```

This is my second datagridview:

```
ID  |  Name   | City
----+---------+---------
5   |  Donald | Oklahoma
7   |  Peter  | Oklahoma
```

Now what I want is that when I clicked a button, the data in second datagridview will be merged to the first datagridview and the result will be like this:

```
ID  |  Name   | City
----+---------+---------
1   |  Alex   | New York
2   |  Mark   | New York
5   |  Donald | Oklahoma
7   |  Peter  | Oklahoma
```

How to achieve this?

Comment: Why does the fact that the first `DataGridView` starts with data in it have any relevance? How would you normally add data to the grid? Why would it be different in this case? Basically, you need to put some thought into this and make an effort at least. We're not here to teach you how to code or write code for you. We're here to help with specific issues. Your not knowing how to do something is not a specific issue because the way to remedy that lack of knowledge is to do some research.

Comment: You should check for `DataGriView` in your browser, and then `How to bind DataGridView`.

Comment: `for each row in datagridview1.rows     
datagridview2.Rows.Add(row)`
or something like that.... that's a point to start.

Answer (score 0):

You either add a row or insert a row into datagrid1 with data from datagrid2.

You do that by lopping over datagrid2 rows and /copying/ them to datagrid1 in that loop.